# Unclear negative sign in rocket propulsion equation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, rocket-science, propulsion

The usual proof of Rocket propulsion goes something like this ([University of Central Florida, Rocket propulsion](https://pressbooks.online.ucf.edu/phy2048tjb/chapter/9-7-rocket-propulsion/))

$mv = (m-dm_g)(v+dv) + dm_g(v-v_{rel})$

where:

- m - initial weight of rocket
- v - initial speed of rocket
- dv - increase in speed of rocket
- $dm_g$ - mass of ejected gas
- $v_{rel}$ - relative speed of gas

Then we get to this equation (by neglecting $dm \cdot dv$)

$m \cdot dv = dm_g \cdot v_{rel}$

Then by realising that $dm_g$ = -dm

$m \cdot dv = -dm \cdot v_{rel}$

This negative sign is off course necessary for the later integration. However I don't see where it follows from. What does it mean to have a mass that is negative and what is 'dm'? I understand it in the derivation sense:

$\frac{dm}{dt} = \lim_{t_1\to t_0}\frac{m(t_1) - m(t_0)}{t_1-t_0} = \lim_{t_1\to t_0}\frac{(m_0-dm_g) - m_0}{t_1-t_0} < 0$

However this feels 'after the fact' knowledge and some manipulation of notation. Where does it follow from formally when we only defined '$dm_g$' as the mass of the ejected gas?

Correction (2023.3.11, 13:19):

Would this be a correct derivation?

$\frac{dp_R}{dt} + \frac{dp_G}{dt} + \frac{dp_{G_{prev}}}{dt} = 0$

where:

- $\frac{dp_{G_{prev}}}{dt} = 0$ change of momentum of previously
  released gas, without adding the mass of the current change
- $m_R + m_G + m_{G_{prev}} = m_{R0}$

$\frac{dp_R}{dt} = -\frac{dp_G}{dt}$

$\frac{dm_R}{dt} \cdot v_R + m_R \cdot \frac{dv_R}{dt} = -(\frac{dm_G}{dt} \cdot v_G + m_G \cdot \frac{dv_G}{dt})$

$\frac{m_R(t+ \Delta t) - m_R}{\Delta t} \cdot v_R + m_R \cdot \frac{v_R(t+\Delta t) - v_R}{\Delta t} = -(\frac{m_G(t+\Delta t) - m_G}{\Delta t} \cdot v_G + m_G \cdot \frac{v_G(t+\Delta t) - v_G}{\Delta t})$

where:

- $m_G$ = 0
- $\frac{dm_R}{dt} = -\frac{dm_G}{dt}$
- $v_G = v_R - v_{ex}$

Which results in:

$m_R \cdot \frac{dv_R}{dt} = \frac{dm_R}{dt} \cdot (v_G - v_R) = -\frac{dm_R}{dt} \cdot v_{ex}$

I might be saying the same thing but this way it seems more obvious that '$dm_R$' and '$dm_G$' are infinitesimal changes rather than infinitesimally small masses.

Comment: *What does it mean to have a mass that is negative and what is 'dm'* What level calculus have you studied?

Comment: As I said in the post, I understand what 'dm' means in the context of an infinitesimal change and I have no problem with a negative change. I had the problem because I thought from the text that $dm_g$ is defined as the mass of the currently expanded gas. (Original text in the mentioned article: 'During an infinitesimal time interval dt, the engines eject a (positive) infinitesimal mass of gas  $dm_g$'). But now I understand it was just a misunderstanding from my side.

Answer (score 1):

$m$ is the mass of the rocket and $dm$ is the change in the mass of the rocket after burning a small amount of fuel. The negative sign means that the rocket is losing mass. In other words, the initial mass is $m$ and the final mass is $m+dm$ after burning a small amount of fuel, where $m+dm<m$ because $dm$ is negative.

Comment: No, the final mass is still $m+dm$, regardless of the sign of $\dot{m}$.

Comment: Oops you are right. I will fix that

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Sorry, it's probably a basic question, but what would stop me from just replacing '$dm_g$' with 'dm' in the initial equation? It still feels like an intuitively correct assumption that I could see myself do naively (to say that the rocket loses the same general mass as the mass of the gas). From what can I know that I used an incorrect sign as an assumption? Is it necessitated by the direction of the integration later on?

Comment: @NemDenemam there is nothing mathematical that determines the sign. It is physical. That is from the conservation of mass. If the mass of the ejected gas increases then some other mass must decrease.

Comment: @Dale but this equation also satisfies mass conservation: mv=(m−dm)(v+dv)+dm(v−$v_{rel}$) and it produces a result with the incorrect sign ($m \cdot dv=dm \cdot v_{rel}$). So what warns me that I made a mistake, other than the fact that I know that the result will have to be decreasing mass and positive thrust? In other words, shouldn't this negative sign come from my initial assumptions, encapsulated in the first equation, rather than from an after-the-fact analysis?

Comment: @NemDenemam that equation is momentum conservation, not mass conservation.

Comment: @Dale I'm sorry then I don't get it. Isn't mass conservation simply '$m_0 = m_1 = m_0 - dm + dm$' in this case?

Comment: @NemDenemam yes, basically. Before the small burn the mass of the rocket is $m$ and the mass of the exhaust is $0$. After the small burn the mass of the rocket is $m+dm$ and the mass of the exhaust is $dm_g$. The conservation of mass says those are equal so $m=m+dm+dm_g$ which gives $dm=-dm_g$. Of course, you could instead define the mass of the rocket after the burn as $m-dm$ and then the conservation of mass would be $m=m-dm+dm_g$ giving $dm=dm_g$. Either is valid, just a matter of defining your variables and applying the conservation of mass

Comment: @Dale I'm probably missing something but why wouldn't the second formulation $(m=m-dm+dm_g -> dm=dm_g)$ produce the incorrect final result $(mv=(m-dm)(v+dv)+dm_g(v-vrel) -> m \cdot dv=dm \cdot v_{rel})$? Also I updated the question with another formulation, would it be correct? (for future reference, is it incorrect etiquette on this site to ask for answer on an update in the comments?)

Answer (score 0):

The total mass is the mass of the rocket plus mass of the fuel is

$$m_t=m_r+m_f=\text{constant}$$

hench

$$dm_r+dm_f=0\quad\Rightarrow\\
dm_f=-dm_r$$

- f fuel
- r  rocket

**The rocket equation**

\begin{align*}
\boldsymbol{p}_t&=(m_r+dm_f)\,\boldsymbol{v}\\
\boldsymbol{p}_{t+dt}&=m_r(\boldsymbol{v}+d\boldsymbol{v})+dm_f\,(\boldsymbol{v}+d\boldsymbol{v}+\boldsymbol{v}_{\text{rel}})\\
\boldsymbol{F}&=\frac{\boldsymbol{p}_{t+dt}-\boldsymbol{p}_t}{dt}=
\frac{m_r(\boldsymbol{v}+d\boldsymbol{v})+dm_f\,(\boldsymbol{v}+d\boldsymbol{v}+\boldsymbol{v}_{\text{rel}})
-(m_r+dm_f)\,\boldsymbol{v}}{dt}\\&=m_r\,\frac{d\boldsymbol{v}}{dt}+\underbrace{
{\frac{dm_f\,d\boldsymbol{v}}{dt}}}_{=0}
+\frac{dm_f}{dt}\,\boldsymbol{v}_{\text{rel}}\\
&\text{with:}\\
dm_f&=-dm_r\\\\
&\Rightarrow\\
\boldsymbol{F}&=m_r\frac{d\boldsymbol{v}}{dt}-\frac{dm_r}{dt}\,\boldsymbol{v}_{\text{rel}}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's a nice way to show it. Although I think there is a mistake in it. In the first line of rocket equation if $m_r$ doesn't include $m_f$ at 't' then it is constant and $\frac{dm_r}{dt} = 0$, isn't it? The $m_r$ can only change in next iteration if it contains $dm_f$ at 't', right? So if we define $m_{Tot_t} = m_r + dm_f$ and use $m_{Tot_t} = m_r$ substitution from line 2 in your comment then the $dm_{Tot_t} = -dm_f$ becomes clear.

Comment: Probably you are right, but  at the rocket equation you use $~dm_f=-dm_r~$ ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question.

Comment: See my answer „the rocket equation „  $~dm_f=dm_r~$

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand what the question is. I will try to reiterate my question differently, maybe it helps a common understanding of what I mean. The $dm_f = -dm_r$ is only true if the $m_r$ is not constant. However at time 't' it looks like you already assumed the whole mass to be both the weight of the rocket and the mass that is going to be exploded out separately. If that is how you meant then I think $dm_f  =-dm_r$ should be  $dm_{rocket+fuel} = m_r - (m_r + dm_f) = -dm_f$, shouldn't it?

Comment: @NemDenemam I agree with you. I just have problem with my own Rocket equation that I wrote at the document, to get the Rocket equation I used $~dm_f=-dm_r~$ which is wrong according to you .

Answer (score 0):

Actually $dm_g = -dm$ means that the mass that the rocket loses in the burned fuel, is the mass of the ejected fuel.The $dm$ is negative as the change is negative(The rocket is losing mass), whereas $dm_g$ has the same magnitude but it represents positive change(mass is add or change in the mass is +ve).
Therefore,we used a negative sign while equating them.

(Sorry if there are mistakes in grammar,this is my first answer).